# How to convert an ActionScript 2 SWF file to an ActionScript 3 SWF file

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2, adobe-captivate

I created a ُSWF file with the Swish max 4. Then I loaded it in Captivate Software. But I got a message saying that "The Adobe Flash file "Test.swf" contains ActionScript 2 while the current project setting is ActionScript 3. This might cause the Adobe Captivate project to work incorrectly or stop working". After that animations are not fully loaded.  How should I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Action-script 2 and Action-script 3 are written differently, there isn't a converter as far as I know. You would have to rewrite the code. Or you can change the project settings to Action-script 2 if you do not need Action-script 3 capabilities.

Comment: All Captivate projects since version 5 are ActionScript 3 ONLY.  Inserting an ActionScript 2 object can cause conflicts.  You cannot change this setting in Captivate.
SWiSH Max does not support some Adobe Flash features such as ActionScript 3.0.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't use Flash or Animate?

Comment: I am a high school teacher and I need to teach these Softwares. I realized that there was no solution to this problem. I just have to increase the slideshow time in Captivate Software.

Answer (score 0):

All I know is that by now, flash is dead. There is still [ruffle](https://ruffle.rs) though. And to work properly, ruffle at the moment currently can only support ActionScript 3.